# DHL Curl returning empty

Tags: php, curl

I am doing a DHL ECommerce API integration.

The below request was provided in the documentation but when I try this in code using CURL library in PHP, it is just returning the below error

I tried to get the error code using curl_error($ch).

Any advice?

Thanks.

Getting me this error.
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Connection: close
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Integration Server", encoding="UTF-8"

Request:

```
{
    "labelRequest": {
        "hdr": {
            "messageType": "LABEL",
            "messageDateTime": "2021-10-11T19:39:46 GMT+08:00",
            "accessToken": "{removed}",
            "messageVersion": "1.4",
            "messageLanguage": "en"
        },
        "bd": {
            "inlineLabelReturn": "U",
            "customerAccountId": null,
            "pickupAccountId": "34324324",
            "soldToAccountId": "324324324",
            "handoverMethod": null,
            "pickupDateTime": null,
            "pickupAddress": {
                "name": "Jerry",
                "address1": "DHL Express (M) Sdn. Bhd.",
                "address2": "Menara TM .",
                "city": "Laksi",
                "state": "Laksi",
                "district": "Laksi",
                "country": "TH",
                "postCode": "10010",
                "phone": "123456789",
                "email": "jerry@dhl.com"
            },
            "shipperAddress": {
                "name": "Jerry",
                "address1": "DHL Express (M) Sdn. Bhd.",
                "address2": "Menara TM .",
                "city": "Laksi",
                "state": "Laksi",
                "district": "Laksi",
                "country": "TH",
                "postCode": "10010",
                "phone": "123456789",
                "email": "jerry@dhl.com"
            },
            "shipmentItems": [{
                    "consigneeAddress": {
                        "name": "Jerry",
                        "address1": "DHL Express (M) Sdn. Bhd.",
                        "address2": "Menara TM .",
                        "city": "Laksi",
                        "state": "PICKUPstate",
                        "district": "Laksi",
                        "country": "TH",
                        "postCode": "10010",
                        "phone": "123456789",
                        "email": "jerry@dhl.com",
                        "idNumber": " 1023",
                        "idType": "1"
                    },
                    "returnAddress": {
                        "companyName": "DHL",
                        "name": "Jerry",
                        "address1": "DHL Express (M) Sdn. Bhd.",
                        "address2": "Menara TM .",
                        "city": "Laksi",
                        "state": "Laksi",
                        "district": "Laksi",
                        "country": "TH",
                        "postCode": "10010",
                        "phone": "123456789",
                        "email": "jerry@dhl.com"
                    },
                    "shipmentID": "3242341234324",
                    "deliveryConfirmationNo": "238643",
                    "packageDesc": "PKG_desc",
                    "totalWeight": 250,
                    "totalWeightUOM": "G",
                    "dimensionUOM": "cm",
                    "height": 120.0,
                    "length": 5.0,
                    "width": 0.0,
                    "customerReference1": null,
                    "customerReference2": null,
                    "productCode": "PDO",
                    "incoterm": null,
                    "contentIndicator": null,
                    "codValue": null,
                    "insuranceValue": null,
                    "freightCharge": null,
                    "totalValue": null,
                    "currency": "THB",
                    "remarks": "remarks to test",
                    "valueAddedServices": {
                        "valueAddedService": [{
                                "vasCode": "PPOD"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "isMult": "true",
                    "deliveryOption": "P",
                    "shipmentPieces": [{
                            "pieceID": 11,
                            "announcedWeight": {
                                "weight": null,
                                "unit": null
                            },
                            "codAmount": 5,
                            "insuranceAmount": null,
                            "billingReference1": "123",
                            "billingReference2": "123",
                            "pieceDescription": "Air Conditioner"
                        }, {
                            "pieceID": 12,
                            "announcedWeight": {
                                "weight": null,
                                "unit": null
                            },
                            "codAmount": 0.01,
                            "insuranceAmount": null,
                            "billingReference1": "123",
                            "billingReference2": "123",
                            "pieceDescription": "Device"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "label": {
                "pageSize": "400x600",
                "format": "PNG",
                "layout": "1x1"
            }
        }
    }
}


function httpPost($url, $strRequest,$userId, $password)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = "https://sandbox.dhlecommerce.asia/rest/v2/label";

    $headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',

    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strRequest);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $this->errorCode = curl_errno($ch);
    $this->errorMessage = curl_error($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Is PHP error reporting turned on? Try running `var_dump($result);` to see what is in there

Comment: var_dump($result); returns null

Comment: Try `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` and look for the `http_code` key to see if you are getting a non-success

Comment: i am getting httpcode as 405

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because the letter "l" in the word "label" should have been capital "L"